# How to make image control button for each image inside the div using css and js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

how to make image control button like close, resize, rotate   button for each images on hover . There is a div in which each image is draggable.

I need to make a image controll button near to each image. That button need to visible only when we touch or moving mouse pointer on the image, that is the button need to show in it's hover effect.

This is my HTML

```js
$( function() {
  var a = 1;
  $( ".child" ).draggable({
    containment: "parent",
    start: function(event, ui) { $(this).css("z-index", a++); }
  }).hover(function(){
    $(this).prepend('<button class="remove"></button>');
  }, function(){
    $(this).find('.remove').remove();
  }).on('click', '.remove', function(){
    $(this).closest('.child').remove();
  });
});
```

```css
.parent{
  z-index:1;
  min-height: 200px;
  background-image: url('http://img.freepik.com/free-vector/white-canvas-background_1053-239.jpg?size=338&ext=jpg');
}
.child{
  position: absolute;
  z-index:1;
}

.remove{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  display:block;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  border-width:3px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color:red;
  border-radius:100%;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 0%, transparent 46%, white 46%,  white 56%,transparent 56%, transparent 100%), -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 0%, transparent 46%, white 46%,  white 56%,transparent 56%, transparent 100%);
  background-color:red;
  box-shadow:0px 0px 5px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class='child'>
    <img src ='https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/softwaredemo/PNG/128x128/Circle_Red.png' />
  </div>
  <div class='child'>
    <img src ='https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-color-halloween-icons/24/Wand-128.png' />
  </div>
  <div class='child'>
    <img src ='https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-color-halloween-icons/24/Candy-01-128.png' />
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/felixtm/x3xb2jwf/7/

i need output like this [image]

i don't need the cross line and border box  , just 3 buttons in three corner one for close one for resize one for rotate

Close button already implemented . For rotation i know the code

```
var rotation = 0;
var rotating = false;
var startX = 0;

jQuery.fn.rotate = function(degrees) {
   $(this).css({'transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)'});
};

$(document).mousemove(function(e){                
   if (!rotating) return;
   rotation = startX - e.clientX;
   $('.child').rotate(rotation);      
});

$(document).on("mouseup", function(){
   rotating = false;
});

 $('.rotateButton1').on("mousedown", function(e) {
   e.stopImmediatePropagation();
   rotating = true;
   startX = e.clientX;
});
```

Please help to implement these three buttons and functionality with this image . Thank you .

Comment: *startX* and *endX* from a mouse coordinate is used as **rotation**? that's wrong! Trigonometry Felix!

Comment: Could you please help to solve this , solve this entire question ?. Thank you .

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan what wrong ? please help to solve this

Comment: Sorry but where is your `.rotateButton1`? You should create a [mcve] that reflects your issue.

Comment: This may help you. You have to fine tune it on your own ;-) https://jsfiddle.net/x3xb2jwf/9/

Comment: @ArturFilipiak thank you friend. Could you please write it in answer section, so that i can accept this answer .

Comment: is it possible to resize the image proportionally with x and y axis ? currently i can enlarge the image to y axis without effecting the x axis . I want to change the image size that is proportional with both x and y axis.

Comment: @Felix , yes, it's possible. I've posted an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For resizing, use [**`.resizable()`**](https://jqueryui.com/resizable/) method of jQuery UI
For rotation, use [jquery-ui-rotatable](https://github.com/godswearhats/jquery-ui-rotatable) plugin.

`.draggable()` and `.rotatable()` apply to `.child` elements and `.resizable()`  directly to images.

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class='child'>
    <img class='child2' src ='https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/softwaredemo/PNG/128x128/Circle_Red.png' />
  </div>
  <div class='child'>
    <img class='child2' src ='https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-color-halloween-icons/24/Wand-128.png' />
  </div>
  <div class='child'>
    <img class='child2' src ='https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-color-halloween-icons/24/Candy-01-128.png' />
  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
var a = 1;

$( ".child" )
  .rotatable()
  .draggable({
    containment: "parent",
    start: function(event, ui) { $(this).css("z-index", a++); }
  })
  .hover(function(){
    $(this).find('.ui-rotatable-handle, .ui-resizable-handle, .remove').show();
  }, function(){
    $(this).find('.ui-rotatable-handle, .ui-resizable-handle, .remove').hide(); 
  })
  .append('<button class="remove"></button>')
  .on('click', '.remove', function(){
    $(this).closest('.child').remove();
  })
  .find( ".child2" ).resizable({
    // to keep aspect ratio:
    aspectRatio : true
  })
  // hide control handles:
  .trigger('mouseleave');
```

<kbd>[**JSfiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/x3xb2jwf/20/)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you friend .

Comment: hi, could you please check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40342500/jquery-draggable-event-changing-the-css-of-child-element